# Tailwind not applying to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I basically did everything on what the instruction had said BUT it is still not working somehow. I wanted to test out things here and there since I am new at this kind of stuff.

**All files**
[image: all files]

HTML FILE

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="src/input.css" rel="stylesheet">  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="text-red-400 bg-slate-300 text-xl">
    Hello world!
  </div>
  <div class="bg-slate-600">
    Testing
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

TAILWIND CONFIG FILE

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}",
            "./main/index.html",
            "./dist/output.css"
],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**output.css file**
[image: output.css file]
**json file**
[image: json file]
**the result**
[image: the result]

Comment: what instructions?

Comment: did you run `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch` as requested in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)?

Comment: also, you dont need to use the input css in the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider checking you have the following in what I assume to be the input file for Tailwind, `src/input.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The `dist/output.css` should *not* be covered by the `content` file globs:

```js
content: [
  "./src/**/*.{html,js}",
  "./main/index.html",
],
```

Assuming `src/input.css` is the input file for Tailwind, then it should *not* be referenced in `main/index.html`.

The path referenced for `dist/output.css` seems incorrect in `main/index.html`, it should be `../dist/output.css`, if the server serving `main/index.html` serves upper-level folders like this. If the server does not, you may wish to instead move the `output.css` file to `main/dist/output.css` without changing the original reference path.

Then, ensure you run to compile the Tailwind CSS rules:

```
npx tailwindcss --input src/input.css --output main/dist/output.css
```

Comment: Great answer! clear and exact

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new at this since I just started learning like a day ago.